# Magento get Customer Data from session id

Tags: magento-1.9, php, customer, session, customer-session

I've create a login function that make the customer login by email and password and return below response

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "message": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "username",
        "firstname": "firstname",
        "lastname": "lastname",
        "email": "mail@mail.com",
        "session_id": "7ead152bcd78c30b3f7415c985ab3d0b",
        "info": {
            "postcode": "1300",
            "city": "city",
            "street": "street",
            "telephone": "1234567890",
            "fax": null,
            "country": "USA",
            "region": null
        }
    }
}
```

So i want to get the `customer data` from the `session id` above but it's not working.

```
$sess = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array( 'value' => $sessId ));
print_r($sess);
```

My Questions:

**1- How i can get the customer data from session id?**

**2- how i can logout the customer from the session id?**

NB: This request from mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

Get the customer data from session:

```
if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
    $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($customer->getData());
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Logout from session:

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('default');
Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend"));
// get login customer data
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
    $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
     //echo $customerData->getId();
}

//For Logout Customer
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->logout();

$data['responseCode']='1';
$data['msg']="Logged Out Successfully";

$data2=json_encode($data);
echo $data2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the customer data from sessions with the following code but this is valid if you are using Magento 2.

**Using object Manager**

```
$om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();  
$customerSession = $om->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');  
$customerData = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getData(); //get all data of customerData
$customerData = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();//get id of customer
```

if you are using Magento 1:

```
 if (Mage::getModel('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
    $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($customer->getData());
} else {
    echo 'Not Logged in';
}
```